# Powershell - Sum of VMs CPU and Host CPU

Tags: powershell, sum, aggregate

Powershell script to sum up all vCPUs and compare to Host CPU.
What I have so far is the following

```
$hostGroups = Get-SCVMMServer -ComputerName "NAME" | Get-SCVMHostGroup | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "*SOMETHING*"}
        $hostGroups =  $hostGroups.AllChildHosts
        Foreach ($hostGroup in $hostGroups)
        {
            $SCVMs += @(Get-SCVirtualMachine -VMHost $HostGroup.Name) 
        }
        Foreach ($SCVM in $SCVMs)
        {
            $CPUCount = $null
$HostLogicalProcessorCount = Get-SCVMHost -ComputerName $SCVM.HostName | Select-Object LogicalProcessorCount

            $answer  = $SCVMs |
            Select-Object CPUCount, HostName  |
            Group-Object HostName |
            Select-Object @{n='HostName';e={$_.Group | Select -Expand HostName -First 1}},
                  @{n='CPUCount';e={($_.Group | Measure-Object CPUCount -Sum).Sum}},
                  @{n="HostLogicalProcessorCount";e={$HostLogicalProcessorCount}}


        }
        $answer | Format-Table -AutoSize

        $answer > answer.txt
```

That's the intention, but of course, the part of $HostLogicalProcessorCount is wrong.
I have the 2 first columns correct

How can I match the hostname?
Later maybe add the ratio to the answer? $ratio = CPUCount/HostLogicalProcessorCount

Expected result is

```html
HostName                   CPUCount HostLogicalProcessorCount
--------                   -------- -------------------------
BLA02SAM4N.DOMAIN.local      128  128
BLA02SAM9N.DOMAIN.local      101  64
BLA02SAM7N.DOMAIN.local      103  64
BLA02SAM1N.DOMAIN.local      105  64
BLA02SAM3N.DOMAIN.lAocal      126  48
BLA02SAM2N.DOMAIN.local       86  64
BLA02SAM8N.DOMAIN.local      115  32
BLA02SAM6N.DOMAIN.local      124  64
BLA02SAM5N.DOMAIN.local      101  128
ALB02SAM7N.DOMAIN.local      199  64
ALB02SAM4N.DOMAIN.local      205  256
ALB02SAM3N.DOMAIN.local      162  64
ALB02SAM5N.DOMAIN.local      171  64
ALB02SAM8N.DOMAIN.local      172  64
ALB02SAM2N.DOMAIN.local      213  64
ALB02SAM9N.DOMAIN.local      172  128
ALB02SAM1N.DOMAIN.local      186  64
ALB02SAM6N.DOMAIN.local      171  128
```

Comment: Since you're grouping on the HostName, the Name property of the group will have that name, so you should be able to do `@{n='HostName';e={$_.Name}}`

Comment: I don't need the hostname, I already have it.
I wanted other properties related to the host.
How can I match the hostname, for example, BLA02SAM4N.DOMAIN.local, and get properties related to the host? and add it to my answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer. Might not be optimised or looking good, but it works. 
So after grouping by and sumarrizing with the data from the VMs (Get-SCVirtualMachine), I am using Get-SCVMHost to fetch data from the related host.

```
$hostGroups = Get-SCVMMServer -ComputerName "au05scvmm" | Get-SCVMHostGroup | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "*SOMETHING*"}
$hostGroups =  $hostGroups.AllChildHosts
    Foreach ($hostGroup in $hostGroups)
    {
        $SCVMs += @(Get-SCVirtualMachine -VMHost $HostGroup.Name) 
    }

$GroupbyArray = $SCVMs |
    Select-Object CPUCount, HostName |
    Group-Object HostName | select-Object @{n='HostName';e={$_.Group | Select -Expand HostName -First 1}},
        @{n='CPUCount';e={($_.Group | Measure-Object CPUCount -Sum).Sum}}


$answer = @()   
Foreach($element in $GroupbyArray)
{

$answer = $answer + 
    (Get-SCVMHost -ComputerName $element.HostName |  Select-Object `
    @{n="HostName";e={$element.HostName}}, `
    @{n="pCPU_vCPU_Ratio"; e={[math]::Round($element.CPUCount/$_.LogicalProcessorCount,1)}}, `
    @{n="Memory_provisoned_Ratio"; e={[math]::Round(($_.AvailableMemory/$_.TotalMemory)*100,6) -as [decimal]}}, `
    @{n="LogicalProcessorCount";e={$_.LogicalProcessorCount}}, `
    @{n="PhysicalCPUCount";e={$_.PhysicalCPUCount}}, `
    @{n="CoresPerCPU";e={$_.CoresPerCPU}}, `
    @{n="CPUCount";e={$element.CPUCount}}, `
    @{n="Host_TotalMemory";e={$_.TotalMemory}}, `
    @{n="Host_AvailableMemory";e={$_.AvailableMemory}}
    )
}       

$answer | ConvertTo-Json
```